# How to render html file in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I was able to open an html file using vba, the problem is, the content is not in the sheet. Its just white. is there a way to open an html file using excel and be able to display the html content?

Comment: Would you like to insert your VBA code  so we can help you?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Html files are understood as web files. Copy the file to text. (foo.html ->foo.txt)
and open it. then you can see the source code as text. This keeps the file from being rendered.  Once can do this manually, for vba, just copy to tmp.foo.html, open, then delete the tmp file when done.